# Generate and parse text files in Java

Tags: java, file

I'm looking for a library/framework to generate/parse TXT files from/into Java objects. 
I'm thinking in something like Castor or JAXB, where the mapping between the file and the objects can be defined programmatically or with XML/annotations. The TXT file is not homogeneous and has no separators (fixed positions). The size of the file is not big, therefore DOM-like handling is allowed, no streaming required.

For instance:

```
TextWriter.write(Collection objects) -> FileOutputStream
TextReader.read(FileInputStream fis) -> Collection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [google's protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview)

> Protocol buffers are a flexible, efficient, automated mechanism for
>   serializing structured data – think XML, but smaller, faster, and
>   simpler. You define how you want your data to be structured once, then
>   you can use special generated source code to easily write and read
>   your structured data to and from a variety of data streams and using a
>   variety of languages. You can even update your data structure without
>   breaking deployed programs that are compiled against the "old" format.

Protobuf messages can be exported/read in binary or text format.

Other solutions would depend on what you call text file : if base64 is texty enough for you, you could simply use [java standard serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) with base64 encoding of the binary stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Jackson serialize to JSON and back

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: Also, Jackson allows one to add custom encoders, if you have some non-POJO classes that you'd like to en/decode.

Comment: The format of the text file is not structured, it's fixed positions (the file will be read by Cobol programs).

Answer (score 0):

Just generate and parse it with XML or JSON formats, there's a whole load of libraries out there that will do all the work for you.

Comment: The format of the text file is not structured, it's fixed positions (the file will be read by Cobol programs). We already do XML and JSON (de)serialization in our project, but this case is special.